# How to prevent Android Studio autocomplete removing adjacent token

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ide, android-studio

If I'm editing an existing line of code in Android Studio, and accept an autocomplete, the following token to the right of the cursor gets eaten:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this behaviour, keeping both the autocomplete plus the rest of the line?

Comment: Voted the question up as the way it is asked is very .. modern ;) >perfect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you press "Enter" it just pastes in the autocomplete, if you press "Tab" it replaces it. I would guess you are always pressing "Tab", so try "Enter" and see if you like how that works.

[Full Documentation from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-suggestion-list.html)

Here's the TLDR;

1. Use **Enter** to insert the selected string at the insertion point.
2. Use **Tab** to replace the string next to the caret with the selected one.
3. Use **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to make the current code construct syntactically correct (balance parentheses, add missing braces and semicolons, etc.)

Comment: Thank you!!! I was always using ENTER and it annoyed me to no end that it inserted the string and not replaced it!